# Starting Rails with Foreman and ruby 2.0.0

Tags: bundler, foreman, ruby-2.0

I'm just upgrading a Rails app to Ruby 2.0.0, deploy to Heroku works fine. `ruby "2.0.0"` is specified in the Gemfile, but when I try to start Rails locally using

```
bundle exec foreman start
```

I get...

```
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

I've installed the latest Bundler, done a bundle instal and I've gor rvm running ruby 2.0.0.

`ruby -v` in the console returns `ruby 2.0.0p0`

I'm just not sure where this is falling down.

Running `foreman start` works as expected. It just wont start with `bundle exec`

Can anyone point me in the right direction? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up including the foreman gem in the app's Gemfile. This works, but since the Gem is deprecated, it's really just a workaround.